# How to update location for every 15 min and send to server after app closed - react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation

I want to capture current location for every 15 min and send that location to server.
I used `react-native-background-geolocation`. It works only in foreground for me but
not in background. Here is my code

```
    const [enabled, setEnabled] = React.useState(true);
    const [location, setLocation] = React.useState('');
    React.useEffect(() => {
      /// 1.  Subscribe to events.
      const onLocation = BackgroundGeolocation.onLocation(location => {
        console.log('[onLocation]', location);
        setLocation(JSON.stringify(location, null, 2)) });
    
      BackgroundGeolocation.ready({
        desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.DESIRED_ACCURACY_HIGH,
        distanceFilter: 10,
        stopTimeout: 5,
        logLevel: BackgroundGeolocation.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE,
        stopOnTerminate: false, // <-- Allow the background-service to continue tracking when user closes the app.
        startOnBoot: true, // <-- Auto start tracking when device is powered-up.
        batchSync: false, // <-- [Default: false] Set true to sync locations to server in
        autoSync: true, // <-- [Default: true] Set true to sync each location to server as it arrives.
        headers: {
          'X-FOO': 'bar',
        },
        params: {
          auth_token: 'maybe_your_server_authenticates_via_token_YES?',
        },
      }).then(state => {
        setEnabled(state.enabled);
        BackgroundGeolocation.watchPosition(
          function (location) {
            console.log('- Watch position: ', location);
            fetch('https://shopql.herokuapp.com/shop', {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({location}),
            }).then(data => {
              console.log('Api called');
            });
          },
          function (errorCode) {
            alert('An location error occurred: ' + errorCode);
          },
          {
            interval: 900000, // <-- retrieve a location every 15 min.
          },
        );
        if (!state.enabled) {
          BackgroundGeolocation.start(function () {
            console.log('- Start success');
          });
        }
        console.log(
          '- BackgroundGeolocation is configured and ready: ',
          state.enabled,
        );
      });
    
      return () => {
        onLocation.remove();
        onActivityChange.remove();
        onProviderChange.remove();
      };
    }, []);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (enabled) {
        BackgroundGeolocation.stop();
        setLocation('');
      }
    }, [enabled]);
```

I tried with this code but this code is not working for me. it works fine in foreground
but not working when app closed. Please help me on how to update current location when
app closed

Comment: had a similar problem previously. You need to force keep your app awake because the OS kills the background processes. What we did (and what Google maps does), is we kept a notification showing for the app to keep it "awake" and allow background processes to run. Don't remember what we did for iOS but it was pretty similar

Comment: did you find any workaround? @JoshiG